# Why do circular "snowrafts" form on a lake during a blizzard?

Tags: waves, weather

I was just out walking along Lake Michigan during a snowstorm and I noticed that the snow was clumping into these interesting circular "snowrafts". They all seem to be about 6 to 10 feet across with a little pool of water in the middle.  I was just wondering if anybody could explain why that kind of clumping into rafts happens.

Check out this video to see what I mean:
[Snowrafts on Lake Michigan](https://plus.google.com/103585488893025173441/posts/6WfVB1tvmXB)

Does it have something to do with the wave height?  Is it so they can move past each other?  If anybody can explain I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested I found the answer to this after doing some more digging.  The phenomenon is called pancake ice.

http://woodtv.com/2015/01/07/pancake-ice-possible-on-lake-michigan-this-week/

The wikipedia for pancake ice states that the rings form from periodic compressions of surface slush at wave troughs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_ice

Now the curious thing is figuring out why it has the given size distribution, but I'll leave that as an exercise for others to try.